# Net present value equations

Tags: finance

I have this problem

> An investor enters into an agreement to contribute $7,000$ immediately and
>   $1,000$ at the end of two years in exchange for the receipt of $4,000$ at the
>   end of one year and $5,500$ at the end of three years.

I tried setting up this problem by equating each of their present values:
$$7000+1000v^2 = 4000v + 5500v^3 \hspace{.3in} [1]$$
Notice that equation $[1]$ can be set up in two different ways:
$$NPV_2(i) = 7000+1000v^2-4000v-5500v^3=0 \hspace{.3in} [2]$$
$$NPV_3(i) = 4000v+5500v^3-7000-1000v^2 = 0 \hspace{.3in} [3]$$

And if I evaluate equation $[2]$ at $i=0.09$ I get $NPV_2(0.09)= -75.05$

while using euation $[3]$ at $i=0.09$ yields $NPV_3(0.09) = 75.05$

Why are they different?

Comment: Because you can compute the NPV for the investor or the NPV for the other  contracting party. The NPV for the investor is the NPV of his/her receipts minus the NPV of his/her contributions. This is what equation [3] yields. The NPV for the other partner is exactly the opposite (negative amount), i.e., the value given by equation [2].

Comment: @GerhardS. woah, I forgot about that xD. Anyways, thanks for pointing that out!